# Nodejs equivalent of Python HMAC signature?

Tags: python, node.js, hmac, digest

I want to generate a signature in Node.js.  Here is a python example:

`signature = hmac.new(SECRET, msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()`

I have this:

`signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRET).update(message).digest('hex').toUpperCase()`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the node manuals as well. It looks correct to me. What about the `;` in the end of the chain?

Comment: Ha ok! Just saying :)

Comment: How embarrasing.  I just checked the two:
Python: http://ideone.com/jXYqa5
Node: http://ideone.com/y4QBpB

They are, in fact, the same.  Which means I must be doing something else wrong with the API I am integrating with.  Thanks for the vote of confidence. :)